# JavaScript - Executar Dados de uma array sempre na mesma ordem

Tags: javascript, array

Bom/Boa Dia/Tarde/Noite, Gostaria de uma ajuda em JavaScript, como faço para executar dados de uma array sempre na mesma ordem, exemplo:

```
var teste = ["valor1", "valor2"];
document.getElementById("id").innerHTML =
```

Como faco pra quando eu clicar um botao o valor do texto seja o valor um, depois quando clicar de novo seja o valor dois, e depois reinicie.Obrigado, desculpe-me pela pergunta enorme ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tens de criar uma variável que guarde a informação de qual elemento da array foi mostrado. Uma flag do indice. E depois cada vêz que clicares no elemento aumentas essa variável de valor.

Um exemplo seria assim:

```
var arr = ['Olá', 'hoje', 'esteve', 'um', 'lindo', 'dia!'];
var index = 0;
var btn = document.querySelector('button');
var div = document.querySelector('div');

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    div.innerHTML = arr[index];
    index++;
    if (index == arr.length) index = 0;
});
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/r8d787d8/

Comment: Muito Obrigado De Novo!